# Why can I not set a Func to return a parameter type to an integer value?

Tags: c#

If a Func returns a value why can I not just simple set it to a return type of the same type as the last parameters in the Func<....Parameter List....>.

**Question: Why can I not set the Func to the return type?**

Or do I have to use the variable returnResult which is declared above?

Neither work.

Code:

```
int tempValueResult = Func<int, int, int, int, int, int, int> myMeth6 = (a, b, c, y, e, returnResult) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(a + b + c + y + e);
    return (a);
};

Console.WriteLine(returnResult);
```

OR--

```
int returnResult = 0;
Func<int, int, int, int, int, int, int> myMeth6 = (a, b, c, y, e, returnResult) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(a + b + c + y + e);
    return (a);
};
```

Comment: It's hard to say what you're talking about, but your second code snipped compiles just fine.

Comment: Are you asking why you can assign a `Func<A1,A2..,An, T>` to a variable of type `T`?

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/l72bdhr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why can I not set the Func to the return type?

Because a function that returns an `int` is a *function*, not an `int`.  The *result* of that function given specific inputs is an `int`.

In both examples, you have not provided any values for the inputs, so there's no value to get back.  It's not until you provide the inputs and evaluate the function that you get a meaningful result.

Your second example works just fine, but you have to provide inputs and capture the output:

```
returnResult = myMeth6(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```